# Calling autoloaded dictionary functions from other autoloaded dictionary functions in VimL (vimscript)

Tags: vim

Is it possible to invoke an autoloaded dictionary function from within another autoloaded dictionary function in Vim script?

I want to have something like this in `autoload/foo.vim`:

```
function! foo#Initialize()
  return 1
endfunction

let foo#MyDict = {}

function! foo#MyDict.say_hi() dict
  echo "hi"
endfunction

let foo#OtherDict = {}

function! foo#OtherDict.call_hi() dict
  call foo#MyDict.say_hi()
endfunction
```

And I want to use it like this from another file/interactively/whatever:

```
call foo#Initialize()
call foo#OtherDict.call_hi()
```

Unfortunately, that gets me an error:

```
E121: Undefined variable: foo#MyDict
```

The call to `foo#Initialize()` is necessary due to a bug/limitation in Vim related to dictionary functions not triggering an autoload.  There's a [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_use/p48GZDesjQc/R2ptcs33v9wJ) thread about this where Bram confirmed the problem.

I'm not sure that's the root of this problem, however, because once the file is autoloaded (via `foo#Initialize()`), invoking dictionary functions works in general.  It's the nested call example above that's giving me an error.

To clarify, this works fine:

```
function! foo#SayHello()
  echo "hello"
endfunction

function! foo#OtherDict.say_hello() dict
  call foo#SayHello()
end
```

It's only nested calls to autoloaded dictionary functions that fail.

Comment: I have a mild objection to the removal of the "viml" tag I attached.  I've posted a [question on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175483/why-is-viml-rejected-as-a-tag-on-stack-overflow) about usage of the tag "VimL" and my defense of it.  I don't want to have the discussion in comments here, but I am hoping that others will read the Meta question and discuss there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same happens when the script is put in the `plugin/` directory or explicitly `:runtime`'d before use. But there's no error when instead of `foo#MyDict` a script-local `s:MyDict` is used. This is unexpected for me, too. Please submit a bug on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).

Comment: Accepting since I think it is in fact a bug.  I'll follow up on the mailing list.